# What is the difference between the Hero, Princess, and Scholar classes?

Tags: 3d-dot-game-heroes

Title says it all. I'm also wondering what exactly the difference is between males and females, in regards to stats.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Heroes start with 5 health and 0 magic
- Scholars start with 3 health and 2 magic
- Princess/Prince start with 4 health 1 magic

That is the stat difference (starting)
(kind of knew / pulled from wiki)

Answer (score 2):

Some people will also have different dialog based on what you are.